# What was the origin of the name "Robin" in the English version of Batman - Dark Victory?

Tags: dc, names, robin

I've recently read *Batman - Dark Victory*, which I own in a translated version in my native tongue. In the second book there's a particular moment where Batman talks with Dick about why he chose *Robin* as his crimefighter identity. Dick replies something like this:

> "My mom called me Robin, because I was constantly doing stuff".

In my version the word used for "*doing*" is "*robil*" which is a nice word play. But I cannot figure out how this sentence is carried out in the original.

**Is there any word play in the original? If so, what is it?**

Comment: Do you want a name specific to Dark Victory, or just the general origin of the name Robin?

Comment: @Edlothiad - He's asking ***"what was the wordplay in the English version?"***

Answer (score 29):

In the English version the joke was that his mother called him Robin because he was always "*[bobbin' along](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tc95FaqWKJA)*"

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Dark Victory - Vol.1 #12**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_Dark_Victory_Vol_1_12)</sup></sub>

Comment: Can't upvote now, but +1 for the video :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! I prefer the translated version though, it's funnier to me ;)

Comment: That video confused me for a while, until I remembered that the American robin is a completely different species.